# QuickReturn with RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am trying to have a CheckBox (which is above the RecyclerView) as QuickReturn. The simple idea would be to hide the checkbox, when scroling up and make it visible, when scrolling down. (as in https://github.com/dbleicher/recyclerview-grid-quickreturn.)

And, it kind of works, but I have a strange flickering when scrolling.

Any thoughts on that?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private CheckBox mCheckbox;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recview);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                // Simple check if moved vertically.
                // React to scrolls of a minimum amount (3, in this case)
                if (dy > 3) {

                    if (mCheckbox.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        mCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else if (dy < -3) {

                    if (mCheckbox.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        mCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        List<String> dataset = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataset);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<String> mDataset;

        public CustomAdapter(List<String> dataset) {
            mDataset = dataset;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(arg0.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.address_card, arg0, false);

            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            viewHolder.mText.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataset.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

            private TextView mText;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check me" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

adress_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I can't seem to re-create the flickering you mention.  What, exactly is flickering?  The checkbox, or the items in the RV?  If its the items in the RV (stuttering on scroll?) please post your ViewHolder and onBind methods.  If its the checkbox flickering, double-check the calculation of height of the check-box and please show the layout XML.

Comment: Hmmm, the flickering is for the CheckBox well as for the CardViews in the RecyclerView. It looks a bit so as if the CheckBox goes permanentyl from `VISIBLE` to `GONE` and back.
I added the complete code...

Comment: Have you looked into this library https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn ?

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml, you have both the checkbox and RV in a LinearLayout.  Whenever you set the checkbox to View.GONE, not only does it remove that view, but it has to recalculate the layout of the RV (and grow it to full_size).  That's a lot of work on the main thread.  Instead of a LinearLayout, add both items to a FrameLayout (RV first, then the Checkbox).  This will make the checkbox float on-top of the RV, but the RV size will no longer change when you hide the checkbox.  I suspect this will eliminate the flickering.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check me" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Using Gravity settings, you can position the checkbox to where you want it to appear (in front of the RV).  If you want it at the top, and you don't want it to obscure the top-most items in the RV (when it's scrolled to the top), the look at the ItemDecorator class (QRBarDecoration) in the same project you reference above.

Hope that helps.